# Keras: How to get layer shapes in a Sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, theano

I would like to access the layer size of all the layers in a `Sequential` Keras model. My code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, 
               kernel_size=(3,3), 
               input_shape=(64,64,3)
        ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2)))
```

Then I would like some code like the following to work

```
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.get_shape())
```

.. but it doesn't. I get the error: `AttributeError: 'Conv2D' object has no attribute 'get_shape'`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to official doc for [Keras Layer](https://keras.io/layers/about-keras-layers/), one can access layer output/input shape via `layer.output_shape` or  `layer.input_shape`.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D


model = Sequential(layers=[
    Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(64, 64, 3)),
    MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=(2, 2))
])

for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.output_shape)

# Output
# (None, 62, 62, 32)
# (None, 30, 30, 32)
```

Comment: "AttributeError: The layer has never been called and thus has no defined output shape"

Comment: @Adrian make sure to define the `inpute_shape` of the first layer correctly. You can check this by calling `model.build()` first.

Answer (score 44):

If you want the output printed in a fancy way:

```
model.summary()
```

If you want the sizes in an accessible form

```
for layer in model.layers:
    print(layer.get_output_at(0).get_shape().as_list())
```

There are probably better ways to access the shapes than this. Thanks to Daniel for the inspiration.

Answer (score 18):

Just use `model.summary()`, and it will print all layers with their output shapes.

---

If you need them as arrays, tuples or etc, you can try:

```
for l in model.layers:
    print (l.output_shape)
```

---

For layers that are used more than once, they contain "multiple inbound nodes", and you should get each output shape separately:

```
if isinstance(layer.outputs, list):
    for out in layer.outputs:
        print(K.int_shape(out))
```

It will come as a (None, 62, 62, 32) for the first layer. The `None` is related to the batch_size, and will be defined during training or predicting.

Comment: `model.summary()` is a good bet in many cases, but ideally I would like to have the shape as an array or tensor

Comment: I get the following error (with the update): `AttributeError: The layer "max_pooling2d_1 has multiple inbound nodes, with different output shapes. Hence the notion of "output shape" is ill-defined for the layer. Use 'get_output_shape_at(node_index)' instead.` I think you have to do the full thing, as in my answer

Comment: You can `K.int_shape(layer.get_output_at(node_index))`, but you will need to get outputs at many indices